# Manual install of pdftk can't find libgcj library

Tags: path, shared-library, pdftk

I'm trying to get pdftk running on my shared hosting account (no root access). I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36121174/354030), mainly:

```
$ mkdir -p [my_project]/vendor/pdftk/lib [my_project]vendor/pdftk/bin
$ cd /tmp
$ git clone https://github.com/millie/pdftk-source.git
$ cd pdftk-source
$ tar xzvf pdftk.tar.gz
$ mv bin/pdftk [my_project]/vendor/pdftk/bin/
$ mv lib/libgcj.so.12 [my_project]/vendor/pdftk/lib/
$ cd [my_project]
```

> You can include the binaries in your app, and then set the environment
>   path to the `bin` folder which holds the binaries.

So, I ran those commands, and I added the bin folder to my environment path. When I try to run the pdftk command, I get `pdftk: error while loading shared libraries: libgcj.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I then edited (rather created) my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the vendor/pdftk/lib folder that had the library.
But it didn't help, it still can't find it.

I just want to be able to use pdftk! Any ideas?

Comment: libgcj.so.12 => not found

Comment: not really sure what i am doing here, does this help?   $ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-673.26.1.lve1.4.18.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@build.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Oct 21 11:58:14 EDT 2016

Comment: please check the directory where __libgcj.so,12__ should be if its not there re-run your set but take note of the __shared hosting__ side to the whole issue. The documentation mentioned should be visited too

Comment: -bash: yum: command not found  @user2782188 the file is there

Comment: please show how and where you added it to you __environmental path path__ it appears that's where the problem is coming from, and what server type are you using just to be sure we're on the same page?

Comment: @user2782188 export PATH=$PATH:/home/rugbymedical156/vendor/pdftk/bin     the server is red hat, i put the info in a comment above